# Function modifying StringFormat

Tags: f#, string-formatting

I want to create a function that would take a `StringFormat` as a parameter, prepend an arbitrary string to it and return a function that takes the correct number and type of parameters and returns a string created with `sprintf` and the altered format.

The goal is to create a function producing results like this (the string to prepend being `#`):

```
xprintf "%d-%.2f" 5 5. // -> "#5-5.00"
xprintf "%A" [42] // -> "#[42]"
```

I've naively tried to do the following:

```
let xprintf (format: Printf.StringFormat<'a>) = Printf.StringFormat<'a>(string format |> (+) "#") |> sprintf
```

That does compile, but I'm getting an `InvalidCastException` when I use it during runtime. I'm starting to think that there is no way this approach could work. Could a custom `PrintFormat` be the way to go? Articles/guides on how to work with the various formatters on a non-trivial level seem to be extremely scarce.

Comment: Try `format.Value` in the body instead of just `format`.

Comment: @kvb Yup, seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `Printf.kprintf`. It returns the formatted string via a continuation, which lets you do whatever you need with the formatted string:

```
let xprintf fmt =
  Printf.kprintf (fun s -> "#" + s) fmt
```

**EDIT:** I think there is a way to work with the format strings directly, but I have never done that. If you wanted to add an additional parameter, you can still do that using `kprintf`, just by doing one more formatting in the continuation:

```
let xprintf fmt num =
  Printf.kprintf (sprintf "# %d %s" num) fmt
```

Comment: What if I wanted to prepend `%d` to the format (since your solution does not change it), thus requiring additional parameter? `xprintf " - number" 5 // -> "5 - number"`. Is that doable?